# React async / await is not waiting in the calling function - but the called function is executing correctly

Tags: reactjs, async-await

I have an image upload method on my react component that calls a helper method in a separate helpers.js class to handle the actual upload, so that I can re-use that method elsewhere in my application.

The react component calls into the helper method, the helper method does its job of saving the file to the server all good.... but the original method is not waiting for the promise to resolve.  I'm sure it is something small I am missing, but I can't see it.

I've read up on all the similar questions here and implemented what I thought would fix it, done a lot of modifications and refactoring, implemented the await syntax in the helper method, backed it out to the promise syntax again etc.  but to no avail.

//Calling method from the react component:

```
async  _uploadPicture(e) {

try {
  const pictureUploadResponse = await HelperMethods.uploadPicture(e);

  if (pictureUploadResponse.success) { //<=======**PUKES HERE**

    console.log(pictureUploadResponse.pictureFullPath);

    this.setState({
      picture: pictureUploadResponse.picture,
      pictureFullPath: pictureUploadResponse.pictureFullPath,
      errorEditMessage: pictureUploadResponse.message,
    });


    console.log(this.state.pictureFullPath);

  } else {

    this.setState({
      errorEditMessage: pictureUploadResponse.message
    });

  }

} catch (err) {

  // error 
  console.log(err);

}
```

}

//the helper method does its job just great...
//the console.log(response.message) line gets outputted just fine...the image is on the server as expected.

// Helper class method

```
 static uploadPicture =  (e) => {

        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('picToUpload', e.target.files[0]);

        console.log("upload control 1");

        try {

              const settings = {
                    credentials: 'include',
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: formData,
              };

              fetch(envSettings.API_URI(GLOBALS.ENVIRONMENT) + '/utils/uploadpicture', settings)
                    .then(res1 => { return res1.json() })
                    .then(response => {

                          if (response.success) {
                                console.log("upload control 2");
                                console.log(response.message);
                                return {
                                      success: true,
                                      message: response.message,
                                      picture: response.imageUrl,
                                      pictureFullPath: envSettings.IMAGE_ROOT_URI(GLOBALS.ENVIRONMENT) + response.imageUrl,
                                }
                          } else {
                                return {
                                      success: false,
                                      message: response.message,
                                }
                          }
                    }).catch(err => {
                          console.log("error uploading image: " + err)
                          return {
                                success: false,
                                message: err,
                          }
                    });
        } catch (err) {
              console.log(err)
              return {
                    success: false,
                    message: err,
              }
        }

  }
```

But the calling function doesn't wait, and falls into the outer catch block...  Why isn't it waiting?

I really appreciate a second set of eyes on this, I am in the forest and can't see the trees.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the await to work, you need to return a promise from your helper class method. You are currently running the promise inside the function and not returning it, thus the await in the parent class doesn't wait for the internal promise. To fix this issue return the fetch.

```
return fetch(envSettings.API_URI(GLOBALS.ENVIRONMENT) + '/utils/uploadpicture', settings).then(...).then(...).catch(...)
```

Comment: Thank you.  I knew it was something small that I just wasn't seeing.

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for. Accidentally I missed return :)